# Disable in-app browsing on the Facebook Lite app

Tags: browser, facebook

By default, many apps open links inside the app using an in-app browser. On Android, this is a version of Chrome, called Chrome Custom Tabs, optimised for in-app use [(1)](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs).

When in-app browsing is disabled, clicking a link results in the default browser app opening and rendering the webpage.

To disable in-app browsing on the Facebook app, users can go to Setting > Media to find a checkbox related to this behaviour [(2)](https://lifehacker.com/disable-facebooks-in-app-browser-to-use-your-preferred-1658842307).

How can in-app browsing be disabled in the Facebook Lite app? This light version does not seem to include the same checkbox as the regular Facebook app.

Comment: I requested the same feature to the developer of Lynket browser: https://github.com/arunkumar9t2/lynket-browser/issues/139

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution for disabling Facebook Lite's in-app browser.
What you need is a rooted smartphone and Lucky Patcher and that's it.

1. Open Lucky Patcher.
2. Click/tap Facebook Lite.
3. Click/tap "Menu of patches".
4. Select "Change the app's components".
5. Select "Disable components (pm disable method)".
6. Scroll down and disable

   - com.facebook.lite.inappbrowser.common.BrowserLiteProxyActivty
   - com.facebook.browser.lite.BrowserLiteInMainProcessactivity
7. Click apply then close.
8. Launch Facebook Lite and open any link and see magic.

Answer (score 0):

The [new update](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.lite&hl=en) (Version 200.0.0.8.117) now open links directly opened in the browser instead of in-app.